# Better way of checking my application environment setting?

Tags: php

I am building an application and I have constant called `ENVIRONMENT_SETTING`. As I am currently developing the application I have it as `define('ENVIRONMENT_SETTING', 'dev');`

Then I am checking at the top of the file what it is. I am currently doing `if` statements like so:

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT_SETTING'))
{
    if (ENVIRONMENT_SETTING == 'dev')
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }
    elseif (ENVIRONMENT_SETTING == 'test' || ENVIRONMENT_SETTING == 'prod')
    {
       error_reporting(0);
    }
}
else
{
    die('Environment setting not set.');
}
```

This to me though seems like a bit too much code for such a simple check. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that better = shorter (or shorter = better) code ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Yes I do.

Comment: Can the constant ever not be defined? I imagine you can skip the outer block. However i dont see any benefit to reducing the length of the code, what you have is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I personally would use a switch statement. It's much more concise. In your case I would do the following:

```
defined('ENVIRONMENT_SETTING') ? NULL : define('ENVIRONMENT_SETTING', 'dev');
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT_SETTING'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT_SETTING)
    {
        case 'dev':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

        break;

        case 'test':
        case 'prod':
            error_reporting(0);

        break;

        default:
            exit('Environment setting not set.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `die()` part, I consider this form as easier to quickly see in which conditions your script will end / die :

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT_SETTING') || die('Environment setting not set.')) {
  if (ENVIRONMENT_SETTING == 'dev')
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
  elseif (ENVIRONMENT_SETTING == 'test' || ENVIRONMENT_SETTING == 'prod')
    error_reporting(0);
}
```